# Comparing two ArrayList of different types

Tags: android, arraylist

In my app, the user can update some data. For example, the images associated. So, I made a db query to know the paths of the images that are already in the Database. I stored the results in a String ArrayList.

I have another custom type ArrayList, BeanFotos. This type has a String which is the path to the images, including the ones that are in the database AND the images which the user just took with the camera.

So, I need to store the images that are not in database, i mean, the one that the user just took.

I am trying this way:

```
for(int i=0;i<listaFotos.size();i++){//listaFotos is the BeanFotos ArrayList
        String ruta=listaFotos.get(i).getFotoPath();
        for(int j=0;j<fotosBBDD.size();j++){//fotosBBDD is the String ArrayList
            if(ruta.equals(fotosBBDD.get(j))){
                listaFotos.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
storeInDb(listaFotos);
```

This way, I get unexpected result: One image that already is in the Database, is stored again. How could I do it properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Compare only object of the same type with equals. So you have to find the "common part", here it seems to be the path

Comment: Another possibility would be to use some kind of hash for the photo and compare that

Comment: can you able to post your two ArrayList and there type

Comment: I am comparing the String array list with the getFotoPath of the custom type array list, which is a String.

Comment: I could form a BeanFoto from the objects stored in the DataBase, but I was hoping it was not necessary...

Comment: Well, i formed two array lists of the same type (both BeanFoto), tried to listaFotos.removeAll(inDatabase) and it is not removing a thing...despite THERE ARE items that have the same values in all their fields...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the Redundancy of data use HASHMAP http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_hashmap_class.htm instead of ArrayList.